# RegEx to validate ip address with wildcard

Tags: regex, validation

I can't seem to get the proper RegEx for validating an IP address, including support for a wildcard char (*), which can occur only at the end. For example:

**Valid**

```
1.2.*
1.2.3.*
1.2.3.4
```

**Not Valid**

```
1
1.2
1.2*
1.2.3
1.2.3*
1.*.3.4
```

I've come close (and found a few similar questions/answers here), but can't get all of the scenarios to pass/fail. Can anyone help me out? BTW - validating octets are 0-255 isn't necessary, but would be cool.

Comment: Why don't you post your best, and closest, attempt(s)?

Comment: Also what about `*` or `1.*` should those pass or fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
^((((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}\*)|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){2}\*)|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){1}\*))$
```

second edition:

```
^((((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){1,3}\*))$
```

Comment: Looks pretty good, but doesn't it require three digits in each piece? (I'd think a {1,3} was warrented.)

Comment: No, turns out you had it working.  Funny you developed the regex but then thought you had it wrong!  In regexpal.com it works, at least.

Comment: Works great. Thank you so much. I messed up in my reqs for the regex. I forgot to say that "1.*" should be invalid, and that at least 2 octets be specified. Can't figure out how to modify it to support that. Any last bit of help there? Thank you in advance man. Appreciate it!

Comment: `^((((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){2,3}\*))$`

Comment: Doesn't meet the ops request.  For example, 1.1.* isn't valid with this regex.

Answer (score 1):

All on one line:

```
^(?:\*|(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d\d?)\.(?:\*|(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d\d?)\.(?:\*|(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d\d?)\.(?:\*|(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d\d?)))))
```

Broken down:

```
^(?:\*|(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d\d?)\.     # Wildcard, or 1st octet plus...
(?:\*|(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d\d?)\.      # Wildcard, or 2nd octet plus...
(?:\*|(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d\d?)\.      # Wildcard, or 3rd octet plus...
(?:\*|(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d\d?)        # Wildcard, or 4th octet
))))$                                          # Close up shop
```

Alternatively:

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d\d?)\.){0,3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d\d?)|\*)$
```

Comment: This regex works the best.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Doesn't match 81.107.235.38

Comment: LOL.  First to notice in 10 years.  I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Match up to 3 parts and then a wildcard, or a regular IP:

```
^((\d{1,3}\.){1,3}\*|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})$
```

Or, if you want to also validate the numbers, change the `\d{1,3}`s to `(1?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])`.

Comment: This looks good, but you need to put everything except the anchors into a group or add anchors next to the `|`, otherwise it means "match wildcard IP at start of string or regular IP at end of string".

Comment: @F.J: Oops, you're right. It went through a couple of changes and I missed that :) Thanks.

Comment: 1.1.* not valid with this regex

Comment: @user3335999: `/^((\d{1,3}\.){1,3}\*|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})$/.test('1.1.*') === true`

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
\b((?:(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])|(?\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){0,3}\*))\b
```

If you are validating entire string to be a IP address, then replace `\b` with `^` (beginning) and `$` (end), otherwise it will be looking for match within string.

Answer (score -1):

```
^(?:(?:[0-1]\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])|(?:\d{1,2}))(?:(?:(?:\.(?:(?:[0-1]\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])|(?:\d{1,2})))){3}|(?:\.(?:(?:[0-1]\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])|(?:\d{1,2}))){0,2}\.\*)$
```

Here's a short ruby script to show construction and validate results:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

octet2 = /(?:\d{1,2})/
octet3 = /(?:[0-1]\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])/
octet = /(?:#{octet3}|#{octet2})/
dot_octet = /(?:\.#{octet})/

trailing_wild_ip = /^#{octet}(?:(?:#{dot_octet}){3}|#{dot_octet}{0,2}\.\*)$/

%w{
1.2.*
1.2.3.*
1.2.3.4
1
1.2
1.2*
1.2.3
1.2.3*
1.*.3.4
}.
  map {|ip| [ip, ip.match(trailing_wild_ip) ? 'valid' : 'invalid' ] }.
  each {|ip,match| puts "#{ip} => #{match}" }


# output:
1.2.* => valid
1.2.3.* => valid
1.2.3.4 => valid
1 => invalid
1.2 => invalid
1.2* => invalid
1.2.3 => invalid
1.2.3* => invalid
1.*.3.4 => invalid
```

Comment: @burning_LEGION right you are, I've edited a more strict octet match.

Comment: 1.1.* doesn't match

Answer (score -1):

Nice and short

```
^((\d+\.){3}\d+|(\d+\.){1,3}\*)$
```

With the regex modifier that lets ^ and $ match at line start/end

Comment: 1.1.* doesn't match

Comment: @user3335999 It *does* match https://regex101.com/r/VzmWrP/1