# Javascript and Regex for valid IP with Wildcards

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been looking at regular expressions for validating the format of an IP address, and although I have one that work for a full IP address (all 4 octets have values) my requirement is to be able to use wildcards on the IP such as 65.66.100.* or 65.66.*

How could the function below be altered to include such conditions that the two example IPs above would pass?

```
function ValidateIPaddress(ipaddress) {  
  if (/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(ipaddress)) {  
    return (true)  
  }  
  alert("You have entered an invalid IP address!")  
  return (false)  
}
```

Comment: Does the wildcard always have to be at the end, or would the likes of `*.65.66` or `66.*.65.100` be valid too?

Comment: Does it mean you want to allow a string like `*.*.*.*`?

Comment: Also, given you're using wildcards in IP addresses, you may want to look into CIDR notation, depending on what you're doing with them.

Comment: I am not that experienced in RegEx, but wouldn't adding `|\*` to each group work? https://regex101.com/r/43i1kP/2/

Comment: @yuriy636: No, it won't match `65.66.*`

Comment: And should `*` alone be matched then?

Comment: We would only be allowing the last two octets to be wildcards, so `65.66.*` or `65.66.67.*` should pass but anything else like `*.65.66` or `66.*.65.100` should fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11301754/7114764):

```
var regex = /^((((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}\*)|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){2}\*)|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){1}\*))$/g;
```

it matches all this schemes:

```
1.2.*
1.2.3.*
1.2.3.4
```

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/QnfVc4/1

so your code'd be like this:

```
function ValidateIPaddress(ipaddress) {  
  if (/^((((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}\*)|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){2}\*)|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){1}\*))$/g.test(ipaddress)) {  
    return (true);
  }  
  alert("You have entered an invalid IP address!")  
  return (false)  
}
```

Demo:

```js
function ValidateIPaddress(ipaddress) {  
  if (/^((((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}\*)|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){2}\*)|(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){1}\*))$/g.test(ipaddress)) {  
    return (true);
  }  
  //alert("You have entered an invalid IP address!")  
  return (false)  
}

console.log("test for 127.0.0.1 ->", ValidateIPaddress("127.0.0.1"))
console.log("test for 127.0.0.* ->", ValidateIPaddress("127.0.0.*"))
console.log("test for 127.0.* ->", ValidateIPaddress("127.0.*"))
console.log("test for 127.* ->", ValidateIPaddress("127.*"))
console.log("test for 127.0 ->", ValidateIPaddress("127.0"))
```

Comment: It matches `1.*` as well while should not.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do what you're looking for :

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)|\*)|\*)$
```

To break it down, I added two `|` at the end of your current regex. The last one verifies that either a number or a `*` is present after the last dot, and the one before verifies that the two last bytes are either in the current numbers form, or is simply a `*`.

You can verify its behavior here : https://regex101.com/r/jFq85T/1

Answer (score 0):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^(?=(?:[^.]*\.){2,3}[^.]*$)(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){1,3}(?:\.\*)?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q3IPYX/1)